# Defining an OpenGL unit

Tags: c++, opengl, mathematics

I have read that you can define your OpenGL unit by using `glViewport`.
As far as I understood if you use something like `glViewport(0,0,600,600)` then 1 OpenGL unit = 600 pixels. Now my problem is what happens if the 2 sizes aren't equal? How do you calculate your OpenGL unit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

glViewport actually defines the size of your window, so `glViewport(0,0,600,600)` defines a window of `600 x 600`.

By default opengl's coordinate system sees `0,0` as the center of your window and `1,1` as the upper right hand. If you want to change that you use either [glOrtho](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) or [gluPerspective](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml). Using `glOrtho` to figure the unit/pixel ratio is easy:

given:

```
glViewport(screen_left,screen_top,width,height);
glOrtho(negative_x,positive_x,negative_y,positive_y,positive_z,negative_z);
```

where:

**Screen coordinates**

```
screen_left // the x coordinate that your window is created at 
// relative to your screen
screen_top // the y coordinate that your window is created at 
// relative to your screen
```

[image: how screen coords are seen]

**Opengl Coordinates**

```
negative_x // the left x coordinate that opengl sees
positive_x // the right x coordinate that opengl sees

negative_x // the bottom y coordinate that opengl sees
positive_x // the top y coordinate that opengl sees
```

[image: Opengl coordinates]

Be sure to note that screen coordinates are **not** opengl coordinates

then:

```
x_ratio = (positive_x - negative_x)/width;
y_ratio = (positive_y - negative_y)/height;
```

Try [this tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/OpenGL/index.php)'s lesson 2 & 3 on setting up the viewport correctly.

Comment: Thnx for the turotrial,now i think i do understand what Viewport actually does.But giving the fact that I do render a whole screen => my left/top will be 0 which means x_ratio=y_ratio=1 if my math is right.

Comment: Ah, I should have explained that better. left and top are independent entirely of where your screen is located. I'll edit to see if I can clarify.

Comment: So that means i set those values however i want using glOrtho?

Comment: *_x and *_y happen to be values that you can pick. If I want my coordinates on screen to be x:(-100,50),y:(-60,20),z(-10,10) I would call glOrtho(-100,50,-60,20,-10,10); At that point its a matter of preference

Comment: Thnx a lot for this answere :D Helped me a LOT!

Comment: These functions are deprecated as their operate on the OpenGL fixed function pipeline matrices, which are deprecated. You shouldn't advise using them.

Comment: For the sake of ease of learning I recommend sticking with these until you get more used to working with OpenGL. They are older and therefore have more tutorials behind them. Plus, they are easier to understand for someone just starting out (no matrix math involved).

Answer (score 0):

glViewport is just a transformation; see [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html) for an explanation of where it fits into the pipeline and how it's applied.  It may be helpful to think of it as defining an area of the window to draw to, but you should also understand that in reality it's something else.

Regarding "units", OpenGL does not define any "units" at all at any stage in it's pipeline, nor does it provide any means by which you may do so.  It's up to you to decide how co-ordinates map to "units" in your own program (C/C++/etc) code; so for example if you see a call to glTranslate you get both the choice of and the responsibility for what the values passed to it mean in terms of your own code.